# Did God create life forms containing infinite wisdom

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, science, biology

In Tehilim King David said (92:5): "How great are Your works, Lord, how deep your thoughts!"

According to Chazal (Torah sources, ideally Talmud, Midrash but can be Rishonim also) does this mean God created life forms (ex. human body) with infinite wisdom, meaning it can be studied endlessly and never fully understood or just that it is very, very complex.

Our scientific progress seems to show the latter for in biology and microbiology, we are still discovering more and more wisdom.

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify: What makes you think that Chazal may say this?

Comment: @IsaacMoses this ok?

Comment: Not in my opinion. Right now, the form of the question is: *A* seems to be true about the world (no citation). Do Chazal say *A*? I still don't get why you think that Chazal may say this.

Comment: Related Meta discussion: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/is-a-question-that-asks-what-does-judaism-think-of-x-possibly-off-topic

Comment: @IsaacMoses because it seems to be true, though can't be sure. am looking for sources in chazal which shed light on this

Comment: Definitely seems that Hashem created the world with infinite (rather than finite) wisdom. I only have modern sources, though.

Comment: @LN6595 like what? please share

Comment: See Rabbi Avigdor Miller's works. And Chovos Halevavos shaar habechinah.

Comment: @LN6595 chovos halevavos is modern source?

Comment: Chovos Halevavos is 500 years and an era away from Chazal of the Talmud, mishna, gemarah, and midrashim. It comes from the time of the rishonim, who are on a vastly different level than Chazal. But I guess it's old compared to truly modern sources. What can I say? We have a very, very old Torah...

Comment: @IsaacMoses still unclear?

Comment: ray, I believe that reality likely supports your idea and that there could well be support for it in Chazal somewhere, but this post does not convince me at all as to the likelihood of the latter.

Comment: @IsaacMoses why is it so essential to the question that there is strong likelihood to the latter? thanks

Comment: In my opinion, the reader of this question is not given a Juadism-based reason to expect that working to find an answer to the question is worthwhile. "I thought of this philosophical proposition," by itself, tells me why the author wants to know if the proposition is valid, but not why anyone else should care to know, and certainly not why anyone else should expect that searching for the concept in Chazal may be fruitful.

Comment: @IsaacMoses studying the wisdom in nature and deriving therefrom proofs of Gd is a big part of judaism. this is counted as a major duty of every jew in the shaar bechina in chovos halevavos. should i add this in question?

Comment: ray, if you've got sources that could help motivate this question, please [edit] them in. If you're saying that the final sentence in this post is therefore sufficient motivation, I'd be more inclined to agree if it was better-documented.

Answer (score 2):

The [Medrash in Lech Lecha](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%98_%D7%99%D7%93) said that even if all the learned get together they  won't be able to breath life into a gnat.

This doesn't object to being able manipulate, or perhaps even create, body parts. But it does state that humans can't produce real, functioning life.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: @yEz Well, by saying that humans are incapable of producing it, it implies that it is something that science cannot reach.

Comment: The question was if it can be understood, not reached. If by reached you meant understood, then I don't see why that follows. I can't produce a minute, but I can understand what a minute is.

Comment: @yEz cannot reach does support that cannot understand though not a full proof

Comment: @yEz Saying you understand what a minute is is like saying you understand what a hand is.

Comment: @HaLeiVi - that's because us physical beings have no access to _spiritual technology_ which is needed to breath life into items. Not because we don't understand the mechanics of it.

Comment: @DannySchoemann In that case you are completely denying science that which they consider to be within their realm. You are saying that life is not at all scientific.

Comment: _Denying science?_ That's funny. You could also deny that 1+1=2 for most values of 1. I'm just saying that the fact that Science will never control the Neshomo doesn't answer whether Tehilim 92:5 is about infinite or very-complex as the OP wondered.

Comment: @DannySchoemann I'm not quite sure of your premise, that it is something we fully understand but just can't reach. Why can't we reach it? When we understood the subatomic we got to manipulate it. And actually if the Medrash is worried about the spiritual part, רבא ברא גברא. If the body is ready we can indeed send in a soul, or perhaps do a soul transplant, if we were to understand it.

Comment: @DannyShoemann But my comment to you was that you are going against the premise of the OP that living organism is scientific. He is asking if it is infinite or complex but possible to get there. You are saying it is not physical at all. My answer is assuming life is scientific, especially of an inch worm.

Comment: it would be strange how a finite creature with finite atoms can be infinite in wisdom. but then again the torah is like that in some way.

Comment: @DannySchoemann what do you mean by breathe life? are you saying life is more than just laws of physics? it seems when we look at cells everything follows the laws of physics

Comment: @ray - Precisely! Life is more than just the laws of physics. The _Neshomo_ is invisible under the microscope - and that's what makes people _come to life_ or _drop dead_. The Neshomo is beyond the scope of the OP, as I see it.

Comment: @DannySchoemann but where is the neshama manifest? when we look in cells everything follows the laws of physics. we dont see anything miraculous. so what effect does the neshama have on the physical

Comment: @HaLeiVi I don't know why those are the same. Nor do I know what your point is.

Comment: @yEz not the same but definitely one supports the other and so far cells have reached the point where it is almost beyond conception

Comment: @yEz, my comment on minute=hand? My point is that you don't understand the makeup of a minute if you don't understand the foundation of time, but you can identify *what* it is. The same goes for a hand of the body. I know what it is but not how to make one.

Comment: @ray - Everything _ follows the laws of physics_ except _life & death_, for which there doesn't seem to be an explanation why suddenly some folks drop dead. Nor why we can't revive perfectly healthy people who drop dead, while some really ill people live a really long time. (You won't see anything miraculous under a microscope. The Neshomo is not _miraculous_, it's _out of this world_ - the Neshomo isn't part of our _dimension_, same way you can't see Kedusha or prophecy under a microscope.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann yes you cant see the neshama. but why can't you see it's effect? under the microscope all you see is machines. all of which obey the laws of physics. things die because these machines can no longer function. thnx

Comment: @HaLeiVi I am just not grasping what you mean. I know everything there is to know about a minute but I can't make one. I don't understand why identifying the "what" isn't the subject here - if I can identify the what, in its entirety, that means it is finite, and yet I can't make one. "Can't understand how to make one" and "can't understand what it is" seem very different to me and I see no reason to conflate them.

Answer (score 1):

Maimonides states (Mishnah Torah, [Yesodei HaTorah 2:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1102.htm)):

> והיאך היא הדרך לאהבתו, ויראתו:  בשעה שיתבונן האדם במעשיו וברואיו הנפלאים הגדולים, ויראה מהם חכמתו שאין לה ערך ולא קץ--מיד הוא אוהב ומשבח ומפאר ומתאווה תאווה גדולה לידע השם הגדול

Translation:

> How does a person come to love God and fear Him? When a person looks at God's actions and His creations that are wondrous and great, and the person will see from them God's wisdom that has no measure and no end, he will immediately love, praise, extol, and and crave a great craving to know His great Name.

Maimonides is saying that the wisdom in God's creations is infinite ("has no measure and no end"). That means that with all science's discoveries, they will never get to the end of the wisdom in God's creations.